# Help understanding working of KeyBERT for keyphrase extraction

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert, tokenization, document-understanding

I'm fairly new to reading and understanding research papers, so I wanted to get a second opinion on whether my understanding of KeyBERT was correct. Here is a high level overview of my understanding with an example -

- example sentence - “I like reading. I enjoy swimming. Reading is fun.”
- let stop_words = None, ngram_range = (2, 2) that means bigrams will be considered, let number of candidate words we want to return ( top_n ) =  2
- steps -

  - sentences will be split into unique bigrams ( 2 words ) - [ ‘i like’, ‘like reading’, ‘i enjoy’, ‘enjoy swimming’, ‘reading is’, ‘is fun’ ]
  - this list is passed to BERT for embedding. BERT will encode each element of the list and return a list of vectors v1,...,v6
  - The document is also passed to BERT for embedding, and a vector v7 representing the document is returned.
  - if seed_keywords, i.e. words that should be given more importance are given as a parameter, they are also embedded into vectors, and mean, say c1, of those vectors is taken. This vector c1 is then added to document vector v7.
  - it computes a similarity score between each of the candidate embedding vectors v1,v2,...,v6 with the document embedding vector v7. it uses cosine similarity for this.
  - it sorts the candidate vectors in descending order by similarity score, and returns the top 2 ( top_n ) vectors

Let me know if I'm missing any details. Also, are there any better alternatives for the task of keyphrase extraction for specific domain?